# C# How to Unit Test a Method that has multiple Inputs and Outputs?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

I've been tasked to implement unit tests for a lot of modules in a firm and the only Problem I've encountered so far is for Methods where they have about 20 Input Variables and 15 Output variables. How do I even check for so many possibilities?

Comment: Chances are you need to refactor, in order to make your life easier. But how about you give us an example of your code so we can have a look

Comment: FYI: [Single-responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i guess then method looks something like this:

```
public Output Process(T1 input1, ..., T20 input20) { ... }
```

where `Output` would be

```
public class Output
{
    public OutputT1 Output1 { get; set; }
    ...
    public OutputT15 Output15 { get; set; }
}
```

So your test method could look like this:

```
[Fact]
public void TestProcessing()
{
    // Arrange
    var input1 = new T1(); // set some appropriate data
    ...
    var input20 = new T20(); // set some appropriate data

    // Also set expected values
    var actualOutput1 = new OutputT1();
    ...
    var actualOutput15 = new OutputT15();

    // Act
    var output = _sut.Process(input1, ..., input20);

    // Assert
    Assert.Equals(output.Output1, actualOutput1);
    ...
    Assert.Equals(output.Output15, actualOutput15);
}
```

Comment: I see so in this case it is not wrong to do multiple "actual" and "expected" variables?

Comment: @Wamb0 It's indicator that you should refactor the method for it to do less: take less params, do less logic and return less data. But if you have already method like that, there's no other way around it and you have to write unit test like this :)

Comment: sadly all the methods are already given. I guess there is no way around then.

Comment: So i guess that's the way :) If the answer is one that you looked for please mark it as accepted :)